# Is there a better way to do disable on checkbox?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, user-interface

I am working on an application that has a lot of checkboxes that start off unchecked, and each one has an associated textbox which is disabled until the checkbox is checked.

I am going through and currently one by one doing an "if checked, enable, if uncheced, disable" - however it is taking forever!

Is there a quicker way / method I should be using that will speed up this process?

I did not state the language as I am not sure it matters - I am programming in VB, however I just want a shove in the right (language independent) direction and I can research further from there.

Comment: ... Not sure on tags, why is best-practices no longer allowed?

Comment: Re: your question, what UI are you using?  Re: the tag, its part of the effort to clean out subjective questions; partially because we now have programmers.stackexchange.com, which is more appropriate for best-practices questions.

Comment: WinForms? WPF? HTML? Silverlight?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not just create a control that has a checkbox and textbox and handles the enabling/disabling of the textbox within that control?

Comment: This is what I usually do and works great! No need of complicated events or looking at control names.

Comment: This will only help if the controls are next to eachother.

Comment: true.  I had assumed that they were adjacent but nowhere does the OP state this

Comment: The controls are next to each other, however I would like to try a different approach as the layout may change in the future.

Comment: Whilst I ended up writing a module to do some other work, this actual problem that the question was about was solved by your answer and writing it once as a control. For that reason, I am going to mark you as the answer.

Answer (score 6):

You can make a function that takes a checkbox and a textbox and handles the checkbox's event to disable the textbox.

You can then simply call the function once for each pair.

For example:  (in C#)

```
void BindCheckbox(CheckBox checkbox, Control targetControl) {
    targetControl.Enabled = checbkox.checked;
    checkbox.CheckedChanged += delegate { targetControl.Enabled = checbkox.checked; };
}

BindCheckbox(someCheckbox, someTextbox);
```

Comment: +1 I like your solution a lot more than mine. it does not break if you rename your object.

Comment: I have tried to implement this, however it isn't perfect as I would prefer a way that each one would just work without having any manual code behind each... I think I may go for the control method instead, but thanks very much as I hope this method will help me on another project.

Comment: Many thanks - I went for a hybrid way and put the code in a control so I only needed to write the code once and it worked on all instances - however I also wrote a module for other code which I never would of thought about before you showed me this. So, thank you very much for your help - however, Dustin Hodges answer is what I actually specifically went for - This was however very good and I wish there was a way to mark two answers.

Answer (score 0):

If you can include them in the same containing element, such as `<td>` you do a generalized `onchange` for the checkbox. If not, just tweak the DOM transversal of the below code to find the correct textbox.

## jQuery

```
$('input:checkbox').change(function() {
   //$(this).siblings('yourTextbox').attr('disabled',!this.checked);
});
```

Here's a fiddle, for demonstration purposes: http://jsfiddle.net/robert/WTAw8/

**Edit**
I think I completely misunderstood the language you were looking for.... this is jQuery/Javascript based... so ignore this if you're not doing web based.

Comment: Reading through it the first time I had to go back and read it again as he said "language independent"

Answer (score 0):

You could have all the checkboxes call one single event handler, passing along some identifier. And in the event handler, disable/enable the associated textbox based on that identifier. (I'm assuming each checkbox/textbox pair are somehow named similarly)

Answer (score 0):

One method I have used for a similar issue is use the `Name` Property of the checkbox, name your text field something similar, and they can reference each other.

C# example

```
//assume the checkboxs are named cbxfield1, cbxfield2, ect. and the text box is named txtfield1, txtfield2, ect.

public void CheckBoxChecked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     var checkBox = (CheckBox)sender;
     var name = checkNox.Name.Substring(3);
     var textBox = (TextBox)containerWithTextFields.Controls["txt"+name];
     textBox.Enabled = checkBox.Checked;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would add a panel for each radio button textbox combo you have on your page. In the panel make sure that the checkbox and associated textbox are contained within it. Then in your .vb file of the form add the following. Make sure you add a handler for each checkbox's checkchanged event.

```
Private Sub chk_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
    ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles _
    chk1.CheckedChanged, chk2.CheckedChanged
    Dim chk As CheckBox = CType(sender, CheckBox)
    For Each ctrl As Control In chk.Parent.Controls
        If ctrl.Name <> chk.Name AndAlso ctrl.GetType() Is GetType(TextBox) Then
            CType(ctrl, TextBox).Enabled = chk.Checked
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another try at an answer that I think is closer to what the OP wants.  Create a check box/text box manager control to map check boxes to text boxes similar to what [this](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/ajax/examples/manager/firstlook/defaultcs.aspx) telerik radajaxmanager control does.
Then you register a check box with the manager and then register for each text box you want to enable/disable.

Object model would something like this:

```
Public Class CTManager
    CheckToTextMappingCollection Mappings
End Class

Public Class CheckToTextMappingCollection
    Inherits List(Of CheckToTextMapping)
End Class

Public Class CheckToTextMapping
    Public Property CheckBox As CheckBox
    Public Property IEnumerable<TextBox> AffectedTextBoxes

    Public Sub New(ByVal CheckBox As CheckBox)
        Me.CheckBox = CheckBox

        AddHandler CheckBox.CheckedChanged, AddressOf CheckBoxChanged
    End Sub

    Public Sub AddTextBox(ByVal TextBox As TextBox)
        AffectedTextBoxes.Add(TextBox)
    End Sub

    Public Sub CheckBoxChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
        For Each tb As TextBox in AffectedTextBoxes
            tb.Enabled = CheckBox.Checked
        Next
    End Sub
End Class

**** Untested ****
```

Doing it this way makes it more extensible (different rules for enabling/disabling could go in the event handler etc.) and separates the logic for handling this nicely into its own object.